Причина несогласования приложений: о рыбе карпе или о рыбе карп?

Вот название статьи: Все о рыбе карп.  Симпатичная рыбка! Но почему не склоняется видовое приложение карп при родовом понятии: о рыбе карпе?

Многие мечтают о профессии (какой) журналиста. Да, конечно. Но почему использована форма Р.п. существительного вместо приложения?

Эти вопросы уже задавались на форуме, но удовлетворительный ответ не был получен, да и тема вопрос не была четко обозначена — несогласованные приложения. Салат из редьки дайкон или из редьки дайкона? Склонение с родовым словом (2)

В Сети достаточно информации о несогласованных приложениях, но обычно просто перечисляются их виды. Однако названная в вопросе тема о частных случаях несогласования и причинах этого явления отсутствует. Так почему же мы говорим: о рыбе треске, но о рыбе карп? Когда переходим от приложения к форме Р. п.: о профессии журналиста.


Статьи по теме:
Приложение как разновидность определения
Употребление несогласованного приложения
Поговорим о несогласованных приложениях
Несогласованные приложения
